# How to Add/Delete/Array in YAML File using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I have this code in yaml

```
cpu-affinity:
    - management-cpu-set:
        cpu: [ 0 ]  # include only these CPUs in affinity settings
```

Now I am using yq version4
I want to modify this cpu array from [0] to a given list by user input and reset it back to [0] if needed.

In one way I can do like iterating and adding like cpu[0]=x , cpu[1]=y , etc
But then to delete it I have to run del command for  every element to reset it to cpu :[0]

Is there any way to directly replace entire array in one command with user input and reset it back to [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you could use the [`env` operator](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators#read-yaml-environment-variable) to load a YAML list and update it dynamically as

To update the entire array with user-input do below

```
user='[1, 2, 3]' reset='[0]' yq '.cpu-affinity[].management-cpu-set.cpu = env(user)' yaml
```

and to reset it back

```
user='[1, 2, 3]' reset='[0]' yq '.cpu-affinity[].management-cpu-set.cpu = env(reset)' yaml
```

Tested on the latest release version 4.23.1